# Write equals method

Tags: java, equals

Is the first equals enough for all cases or should I is it better to use the second one?
I tried both and got the same results, but maybe there is case I didn't try.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Test)) {
        return false;
    }
    Test test = (Test) o;
    return name.equals(test.name);
}


public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (obj == null) return false;
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
    Test other = (Test) obj;
    if (name == null && other.name != null) {
        return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can `name` be `null`?

Comment: What about `@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Test other = (Test) obj;
    return Objects.equals(this.name, other.name);
}`

Comment: @NPE yes name can be null

Comment: @YCF_L that is the same as the second equals method above

Comment: If you use `getClass` in equals, it will not work if `obj` is a subclass. This violates Liskov Substitutability.

Comment: @Andy Turner so it is better to use instnaceof?

Comment: @ArminZierlinger see http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/EqualsGetClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `name` cannot be null, the first method is fine; if it can be null, make a slight modification to the final return statement:

```
return Objects.equals(name, test.name);
```

This just avoids the NPE if `name` is null.

---

Don't use `getClass()` in `equals` checks: it violates Liskov Substitutability with subclasses.

A more detailed description and example can be found in the documentation of [Error Prone's check](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/EqualsGetClass) for `getClass()` invocations in `equals` methods.

Comment: Angeliker Langer has an in-depth look at various type-testing idioms and their ramifications. http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/JavaSolutions/SecretsOfEquals/Equals.html

Answer (score 0):

If name cannot be null, the first equals() should be sufficient. If name can be null, both variants are insufficient (the second equals does not check both names == null).

If name (and all fields that contribute to equals()) is immutable, you should have a look at [Google’s Auto value annotation processor](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) which provides automated generation of equals(), hashCode() and toString().